# How to display the users_ID on the screen with react native

Tags: php, react-native

I made login with PHP and React Native but now I want to display the ID of the user that's logged in. The ID should be showed on the screen that appears when the user is logged in.
I tried several things but I think the way I request the props is wrong. Because the page where I want to show never requests the data that is started in the previous page.

This is the login screen:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as Expo from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    response: '',
    users_ID: '',
  };

  handleusers_usernameChange = (users_username) => {
    this.setState({ users_username });
  };

  handleusers_passwordChange = (users_password) => {
    this.setState({ users_password });
  };

  handleLoginPress = async () => {
    const { users_username, users_password } = this.state;

    try {
      let response = await fetch('http://IP/CodingApp/login.php', {
   
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          users_username,
          users_password,
        }),
      });

      let responseJson = await response.json();
      console.log(responseJson);
      if (responseJson.loggedin) {
        this.props.setLoggedIn(true, responseJson.users_ID);
        this.setState({ users_ID: responseJson.users_ID });
      } else {
        this.setState({ response: 'tekst kwam niet overeen' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.users_username}
          onChangeText={this.handleusers_usernameChange}
          placeholder="users_username"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.users_password}
          onChangeText={this.handleusers_passwordChange}
          placeholder="users_password"
          secureTextEntry
        />
        <Button title="Login" onPress={this.handleLoginPress} />
        <Text>{this.state.response}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the screen that appears after the user is logged in:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const EditFamily = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Your user ID is: {props.users_ID}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default EditFamily;
```

Comment: Why you added "php" tag..

Comment: Where did you added code for navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Read about redux, which is a state management tool, you can save id whenever or wherever you go and use it everywhere.

https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started